# Recipient.Type olCC populates To field on first run

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I'm in a bit of a conundrum. A piece of code that worked before no longer works as I expect it to without an apparent reason.

The particular piece that doesn't work can be simplified down to this:

```
Sub addCC()
dim mail as Outlook.MailItem
dim recip as Recipient
set mail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
set recip = mail.Recipients.Add("myself@mydomain.com")
recip.Type = olCC
End Sub
```

When I run this on the mail item, on the first run it adds the recipient in the To field not the CC field. On subsequent reruns of the sub on the same mail item, it keeps adding the email address in CC as expected. Only on the first run it adds a TO instead of CC.

I was using this piece of code before and it worked as expected. Now it doesn't and I don't know what's going awry.

Comment: Whatever the underlying reason for a change in behaviour, appears you can just add `recip.resolve`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce the problem. The best course of action is to open a support case with MS (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/assistedsupportproducts?wa=wsignin1.0) to ensure this problem gets fixed.

Comment: I'd submit a ticket if I could log into their help site with my corporate account so I don't get prompted to purchase support.

@niton's comment functions as a workaround for the time being. Adding `recip.resolve` before `recip.Type = olCC` line does move the recip from TO to CC.

Doesn't solve the root cause itself, but does _fix_ the problem.